# Use JavaScript for sending/reading sms on Android phones?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I use PhoneGap for developing native apps on Android platform. Previously there used to be a Javascript function for doing that. But currently that function is not included in the their API. Is there a plugin or any another JS based API which I can use to send/read/delete sms on an Android phone.

Plus: Can I get access to the folder where the smses are stored on an android phone?

PS: I know the URI way of sending sms so that wont count as an answer

Comment: You're likely to only find the URL way for most of the APIs because it's a matter of user security and privacy.  In most cases, users don't want apps sending text messages on their behalf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a plugin or any another JS based API which I can use to send/read/delete sms on an Android phone.

There is no support in the Android SDK for "read/delete sms". You are welcome to write a PhoneGap plugin for Android that ties to `SmsManager` to send SMSes, though.

> Plus: Can I get access to the folder where the smses are stored on an android phone?

For starters, there are many SMS clients, and so there are many different stores for the SMSes. I am not aware of any SMS client that offers an API for manipulating those messages. Certainly, the Messaging app from the Android open source project does not have a documented and supported API.

Comment: Then it would be best to use the url. Is there a way to use the SMS URL to send msgs to multiple recipients?

Comment: @web_ninja: If I read RFC 5724 correctly, you can have a comma-delimited set of recipients: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5724

Answer (score 1):

you can access the sms database if you have ("root") its etc/data/data/telephony/mmsm.db or something like that depending on your version google

directory of sms database in android 4.0 then you can use es file explorer or another file manager to access this database...
you can also view deleted sms in this database...